# Jasper-reports and Dart

Tags: jasper-reports, dart

So I've been searching for 1 hour on Google and this website if I can generate reports using Jasper reports in Dart.
Anyone know if it is possible?
Is there any plug-in?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `generate reports using Jasper reports`. Jasper reports is a Java library. You can invoke a Java application from Dart but I think you need to provider more information about what you actually want to accomplish to give you proper information.

Comment: I would like to show a pdf-like page and let the client print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a request from the browser (might be Dart) to the server (probably in Dart according to your question) and the server has to forward the request to a service running in Java or an application built in Java which generates the PDF file and returns the file (or the path to the file) to the Dart server which itself serves it to the browser.

You can make a Java service that accepts HTTP requests directly and skip the Dart server. The Browser can then directly access the Java service that generates the PDF and receive it from there.

It all depends how your infrastructure looks like.

(I don't know Jasper Reports, it might offer some functionality that makes this easier. This is just a generic answer).

You might take a look at this site

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/818313/which-best-way-use-jasperreport-php-application

I suppose this will apply mostly to Dart as well.

I found that Jasper Reports offers a standalone server which allows both above described scenarios 
http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server

There seems not to be a dedicated Dart client available ([like this one for PHP](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/php-client-getting-started)) but Dart is quite capable of accessing a REST API. It's just a bit more manual labor to access the server than with customized a client library.

Comment: Thanks for suggests.
I'll give it a try and see what I can do.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask if you have follow-up questions, but I think for the information you provided it's hard to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Now I'm gonna try iText for Java, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java).
I plan to code a Java app and call it from my Dart server side.
I'm still thinking about the best solution, but I'm looking forward for this.